# Can a website see the file location of a document I upload?

Tags: file-upload, permissions, file-system

While applying to a job, I uploaded a resume to a recruiting website:

`C:\myname\an\embarrassing\path\to\my\resume.pdf`

Can the website see the file path of my uploaded document?

Comment: not in any browser newer than about 8 years old...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No!  Almost all modern browsers change the path to something like `C:\fakepath\filename.ext` in order to protect your privacy.

Comment: @forest It's not included in the upload, but the (fake) path can be read by Javascript as the `.value` of the input element.

Answer (score 2):

Browser security controls prevent client-side scripts from accessing the full path of local resources. JS running inside the context of a browser by default has no access to the file system. HTML5 provides an API as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav) but apparently anonymizes/sanitize output at the browser level.